# Retrieve rows from a table, depending on other tables information

Tags: php, mysql

As a project I have to analyse film reviews to determine whether they are positive or negative.

In MySQL I have one table for positive words, another for negative words, and another for storing a few film reviews.

I just wanted to know how can I create something basic using PHP that will allow me to look at one of the film reviews and then using the positive and negative words, to see whether they appear in the review, to determine if the review is postive or negative.

This is all i have so far, it prints out one review:

```
<?php
// Connects to your Database 
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); 
mysql_select_db("film_reviews"); 

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM review WHERE id = '1'"); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo $row['filmreview'];
  echo "<br />";
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can you describe the structure of your "negative words" and "positive words" table in your question please?

Comment: for both tables they have an id and word column so for example for the negative table
id word 
1  good
2  brilliant ect

Comment: Ok it's more clear, please precise what information you need to tell if a review is positive or negative:
Would you like to make a sum of the matching positive (+1) and negative (-1) words for each film review? if a word is found several times (say X), should it count as 1 or X? etc.

Comment: yes, so when each positive word is found you'd +1 each time then -1 each time a negative word is found and if the total is below 0 then it would be a negative word and if its above 0 it would be a positive word and if the same word is found twice you'd count that twice

Comment: IMO, symcbean's answer already describes the required elements to build a solution suiting your needs. He even proposes relevant improvements to your inital approach. What more do you want?

Answer (score 1):

Leaving aside the methodology which is fundamentally flawed, you just need to split the review into words then join them to your tables. e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE review_words (
  film_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  review_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  rword VARCHAR(30),
  occurrences INTEGER NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (rword, review_id) /* order is important */
  /* you probably want some more indexes too */
);
```

Then the negative words for review with id $revid:

```
SELECT SUM(occurrences)
FROM review_words rw, negative_words nw
WHERE rw.rword=nw.nword
AND rw.review_id=$revid;
```

And the same for positive words.

A slightly better approach would be to keep positive and negative words in the same table (say review_dict) with a weighting factor:

```
SELECT SUM(rd.weight * rw.occurrences)
FROM review_words rw, review_dict rd
WHERE rw.rword=rd.dword
AND rw.review_id=$revid;
```

Note that you'd probably want to normalise the words first - at least stripping whitespace and using consistent case, if not handling plurals in nouns and neutral tense to verbs.

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

{
 echo '<pre>';
print_r($row);
echo '</pre>';

echo "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Sry, the queston has been edited , this was answer to debug the result